# default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am getting connection time out on my both domains `one.example.com` and `two.example.com`.

I have set up the cluster on AWS using kops.

Ingress is inside the default namespace also the services being proxied to are also in the default namespace.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service-api
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-example-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - one.example.in
      secretName: api-example-in
  rules:
    - host: one.example.in
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /customer/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: customer-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service-monitor
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-example-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - two.example.in
      secretName: api-example-in
  rules:
    - host: two.example.in
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: kube-prometheus-grafana
              port:
                number: 80
```

```
$ kubectl describe ingress ingress-service-monitor

Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
Name:             ingress-service-monitor
Namespace:        default
Address:          dns.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
TLS:
  api-example-in terminates two.example.in
Rules:
  Host              Path  Backends
  ----              ----  --------
  monitor.example.in
                    /   kube-prometheus-grafana:80 (100.96.4.3:3000)
Annotations:        certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-example-prod
                    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: true
                    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
```

For installing the controller I followed [this doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws).
I have run only this command

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml
```

I am listing here other information about ingress deployment

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-5wpwn        0/1     Completed   0          3h39m
pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-6z2wx         0/1     Completed   2          3h39m
pod/ingress-nginx-controller-7fc74cf778-64vk2   1/1     Running     0          91m

NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                                      PORT(S)                      AGE
service/ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   100.68.82.233   5e06c70e0a8b9d4b.elb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com   80:31336/TCP,443:30936/TCP   3h39m
service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      100.64.118.59   <none>                                                                           443/TCP                      3h39m

NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           91m

NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-7fc74cf778   1         1         1       91m

NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           10s        3h39m
job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           21s        3h39m
[ec2-user@ip ~]$
```

Comment: you have applied ingress to specific namespaces in which service is exist ?

Comment: That  installation cmd itself created namespace `ingress-nginx` so pods and deployed for the ingre-controller are running on that namespace. But ingress for both file is in default namespace as I have listed output of describe on ingress

Answer (score -1):

Try by checking the API version you are running or your ingress is supporting

you can run : **kubectl api-resources -o wide**

to check the API versions that your networking is supporting. if it's supporting `extensions/v1beta1` you can use it and the example is below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: secret
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: secret
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: core
    nginx.org/websocket-services: core
  name: service-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.example.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: core
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.example.io
    secretName: secret
```

Comment: I have tried, but I was getting deprecation warning. Everything was working fine. Issue happened when nginx-controller pod get down. I had to delete the deployment and create new one.

Comment: you deployed maybe latest version compare to older one running maybe

Comment: I just ran this command `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy.yaml`

Comment: version i am using with api version `extensions/v1beta1` `quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.23.0`

Comment: version i am using is 0.20 maybe

Comment: i tried with helm `helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.publishService.enabled=true` working for me but  yes api version changes is there.

Comment: apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hw1.your_domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes-first
          servicePort: 80
  - host: hw2.your_domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-kubernetes-second
          servicePort: 80

Comment: I tired with configuration posted as answer by you. I got depcrecated warning however the ingress was created, but I am still getting connection timed out.

Comment: which kubernetes version are you using ?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/

Comment: Version `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:12:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:15:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Comment: I checked on aws console. Registered instances for the load balancer are marked as unhealthy while on ec2 section shows all checks passed. Could it be the issue?

Comment: Registered instances for the load balancer ? i think nginx by default create the load balancer and give the IP.

Comment: I haven't registered anything, ingress created load balancer itself  and did registration. But, why status shows unhealthy there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229819/discussion-between-sujeet-agrahari-and-harsh-manvar).